# ASP.NET - AutoComplete TextBox when choose dropDownList Item

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

everyone. I have a web service with all cars in company with data:
CarNumber and CarBrand.

I want, where I choose CarNumber from DropDownList, CarBrand autocomplete in textBox.

**This is my Web controls declaration;**

```
        ddCarNumber = new DropDownList();
        ddCarNumber.Items.Add("-- Choose Car Number --");
        ddCarNumber.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(ddCarNumber_SelectedIndexChanged);
        GetCars();
        this.Controls.Add(ddCarNumber);

        lblCarBrand.Text = "Car Brand";
        txtCarBrand = new TextBox();
        txtCarBrand.MaxLength = 255;
        this.Controls.Add(txtCarBrand);
```

Whit this method i get CarNumbers from Web Service:

```
private void GetCars()
        {
            Service1SoapClient client = new Service1SoapClient();
            UserDetails details = new UserDetails();

            details.userName = "Weber";
            details.password = "!Q2w#4r";

            DataTable dt = client.GetCars(details);

            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                ddCarNumber.Items.Add(row[0].ToString());
            }
        }
```

> I want where i choose CarNumber from DropDown, TextBox autoComplete with CarBrand.

Comment: Show your `ddCarNumber_SelectedIndexChanged` method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is : my ddCarNumber_SelectedIndexChanged Method, This is working, but problem is with Event, not refresh a page... When I push F5 is Okay...

```
    void ddCarNumber_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Service1SoapClient client = new Service1SoapClient();
        UserDetails details = new UserDetails();

        details.userName = "Weber";
        details.password = "!Q2w#4r";

        DataTable dt = client.GetCars(details);

        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            if (ddCarNumber.SelectedValue == Convert.ToString(row[0]))
            {
                txtCarBrand.Text = row[1].ToString();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

in Dropdown selectedIndex Change Event
ddCarNumber_SelectedIndexChanged

Write below code

```
this.Controls.findcontrol("txtCarBrand").Text = ddCarNumber.SelectedItem.Text/Value //Based on your Data DataTextField/DataValueField
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: findcontrol missing refference